# How to speedup PDF file generation using Crystal Report

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports, reporting, data-export

We have a need to export data/reports in PDF files format in bulk (it could be 10,000 files for bigger clients). Here is how we are doing it right now:

1. use a parallel loop to iterate through a list of objects

   - create Crystal Report for each object and
   - export to PDF format.

For smaller lists, it works fine, but as the number of items in the list grows, it starts to slow down and after a certain threshold, it just dies.

Please advise how should this be implemented to be able to generate any number of files. Is there any other way to export formatted data into PDF from SQL server, other than using reports (Crystal or SSRS)?

Thanks

Comment: You could break it down into smaller batches.  For example, only process 10 items at a time from your list, until finished.

Comment: @dubstylee thanks for your input, I tried it at some point and it appeared to be running for >20 hours before I killed the process :(

Comment: I cannot give you an advice for the programming part because there is no code posted. You can try one of the 3rd party tools , which support data driven reports. Data driven reports will allow you to set a query and run a report for each record returned by the query. You can tell the system also what to export send etc. There are even some free tools on the market. Check this list: http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines. I believe R-Tag Report Manager and VisualCut support this.